# Issue with XmlNode.SelectNodes

Tags: xml

I'm getting back from a web service the below xml and I'm try to select the ttContext nodes but specifically I need to parse the contextValue node where the contextGroup = pcSessionID.

I figured I would first make sure I get at the ttContext nodes and then work from there modify my code as I go but when I run the below code my node list contains 0 nodes. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument

xmldoc.LoadXml(e.InnerXml)

e.InnerXml contains the below xml:

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
         xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
           <apSrvResponse xmlns="urn:eTimeWS:eTimeWS">
              <result xsi:nil="true" />
              <dsContext>
                 <ttContext>
                    <contextGroup>PARAM</contextGroup>
                    <contextName>pcPassword</contextName>
                    <contextValue>admin</contextValue>
                    <contextOperator />
                    <contextType />
                 </ttContext>
                 <ttContext>
                    <contextGroup>PARAM</contextGroup>
                    <contextName>pcSessionID</contextName>
                    <contextValue>admin.8c4a11bf-a8e0-3e9e-df11-84e3cd76215d.bJZfvubladuiXKMj</contextValue>
                    <contextOperator />
                    <contextType />
                 </ttContext>
                 <ttContext>
                    <contextGroup>PARAM</contextGroup>
                    <contextName>pcUserID</contextName>
                    <contextValue>admin</contextValue>
                    <contextOperator />
                    <contextType />
                 </ttContext>
              </dsContext>
           </apSrvResponse>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
     </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

---

Dim root As XmlNode = xmldoc.DocumentElement
Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/dsContext/ttContext")

Answer (score 0):

A little complicated with the namespaces.  I used XML Linq

```css
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String = _
       "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope" & _
         " xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""" & _
         " xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""" & _
         " xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">" & _
        "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" & _
           "<apSrvResponse xmlns=""urn:eTimeWS:eTimeWS"">" & _
              "<result xsi:nil=""true"" />" & _
              "<dsContext>" & _
                 "<ttContext>" & _
                    "<contextGroup>PARAM</contextGroup>" & _
                    "<contextName>pcPassword</contextName>" & _
                    "<contextValue>admin</contextValue>" & _
                    "<contextOperator />" & _
                    "<contextType />" & _
                 "</ttContext>" & _
                 "<ttContext>" & _
                    "<contextGroup>PARAM</contextGroup>" & _
                    "<contextName>pcSessionID</contextName>" & _
                    "<contextValue>admin.8c4a11bf-a8e0-3e9e-df11-84e3cd76215d.bJZfvubladuiXKMj</contextValue>" & _
                    "<contextOperator />" & _
                    "<contextType />" & _
                 "</ttContext>" & _
                 "<ttContext>" & _
                    "<contextGroup>PARAM</contextGroup>" & _
                    "<contextName>pcUserID</contextName>" & _
                    "<contextValue>admin</contextValue>" & _
                    "<contextOperator />" & _
                    "<contextType />" & _
                 "</ttContext>" & _
              "</dsContext>" & _
           "</apSrvResponse>" & _
        "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" & _
     "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"

        Dim envelope As XElement = XElement.Parse(input)
        Dim ns As XNamespace = envelope.Name.Namespace

        Dim contextGroup As String = "pcSessionID"
        
        Dim results = envelope.Descendants().Where(Function(w) w.Name.LocalName = "ttContext" And _
                       w.Elements(w.Name.Namespace + "contextName").Where(Function(x) x.Value = contextGroup).Any()) _
                       .Select(Function(y) New With { _
                                  .contextGroup = y.Element(y.Name.Namespace + "contextGroup").Value, _
                                  .contextName = y.Element(y.Name.Namespace + "contextName").Value, _
                                  .contextValue = y.Element(y.Name.Namespace + "contextValue").Value, _
                                  .contextOperator = y.Element(y.Name.Namespace + "contextOperator").Value, _
                                  .contextType = y.Element(y.Name.Namespace + "contextType").Value _
                                   }).ToList()

    End Sub

End Module
​
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond right away but I didn't get my email notification of your response. I can't use xml ling because I'm stuck with using visual studio 2012 and whatever the default .net framework version that implies.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 contains Linq (not 'g') XML.  There is no default setting for libraries.  I uses a lot of different PCs at home and work (VS2008, and VS 2010) and each computer has its own default libraries.  Even the same version of VS on different computers have different defaults.  The IO library is never added to the module and is often used.  Do you mean you never use the IO library?  The standard XML is also not added to the module.  Instead of adding the using statement use System.Xml.Linq.  The using statement just creates a shortcut so you don't have to add the full library name.